# jQuery remodal popup adding hashtag href to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hashtag, remodal

I have a piece of html which basically looks like this:

```
<a id="popap" style="display:none;" href="#modal">Call the modal with data-remodal-id="modal"</a>
```

And then the definition of the remodal popup like following:

```
<div class="remodal" style="width:60%" data-remodal-id="modal">
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <canvas class="canvas" height="160"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="hideit">
        <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modalMainTitle">
                <i class="far fa-save fa-3x"></i>
                <h1>Add to search List</h1>
            </div>
            <p>
                Comment:
            </p>
            <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding:0 41.64% ;">
            <p>Rating: </p>
            <fieldset class="rating" id="ratingSystem">
                <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" autocomplete="off" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-push-3 col-lg-6">
                <div id="infoError2" style="width:100%;text-align:center; margin-right:50px !important; padding-right:45px;" class="alert"></div>
            </div>

        </div>


        @* 0 - User watchlist //  *@
        <br>
        <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel" id="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
        <button class="remodal-confirm btnSaveWatchlist">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then once I call the popup to be executed like following:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".btnWatchList", function (e) {
            $("#popap")[0].click();
    });
```

Once this event is completed I noticed it adds a #modal into the URL that I'm on(and I don't want that to happen).

Once the event is fired I have a url like following:

```
example.com?Ids=12312312412&Date=30#modal
```

But the url should stay like following:

```
example.com?Ids=12312312412&Date=30
```

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening(so that the #modal part isn't added to the url once the popup shows up)?

Comment: Most modal plugins have an open method that doesn't need to use data attribute

Comment: https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#hashtracking - Not sure if this is the right plugin you're using, but as charlietfl said, it should be an available option.

Comment: This can be done, and there's an answer below that points to the method (but it's currently wrong), but I have to ask *why?*  This is normal behaviour for links with hash references in them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no relevant explanation of what is actually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can also as @charlietfl suggested use the method given to you by the libary:

```
 <a data-remodal-target="modal" id="popap" style="display:none;" href="#">Call the modal with data-remodal-id="modal"</a>
```

Comment: Okay I've tried this and added the: window.REMODAL_GLOBALS = {
  NAMESPACE: 'modal',
  DEFAULTS: {
    hashTracking: false
  }
}; part of code as TJBlackman suggested... but doesn't works :/

Comment: It still adds the #modal :/ meh

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the first answer, I mis-read the question and have since deleted the entry (Apologies, new to this but trying to improve :) -).

event.preventDefault() can be used to prevent a method firing off. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

This can be attached to your Anchor Element to prevent the href being amended. This would look like the following:

```
$('#popap').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

Hopefully the above helps and apologies for the first answer :)

Comment: Np @J_C =D and thanks alot for the help... Tried this one as well but doesn't works either xD